# Interconnect two ESP32 trick

Tags: esp32

That now five years that I develope some PCB board and still learning each day. I found a trick to interconnect two ESP32 by link 1 output of ESP32 N° 1  to an input pullup to ESP32 N°2.
That trick allow me to do easy multitasking beteewn two MCUs.

NB: The two MCUs share the same ground and 3.3 VDC supply.

See circuit below:

[image: link 2 mcu]

This basic circuit works, however how can I improve it?

Comment: Improve it in what way?

Comment: Leave out R1 (and replace with a link)?

Comment: improve in the way that inputpullup of esp32 n°2 is  Floating State when output esp32 N°1 is low